# Surprising behaviour of enumerate function

Tags: python

I wrote some Python code using the enumerate function.

```
A = [2,3,5,7]

for i, x in enumerate(A):
    # calculate product with each element to the right
    for j, y in enumerate(A, start=i+1):
        print(x*y)
```

I expected it to calculate 6 products: 2*3, 2*5, 2*7, 3*5, 3*7, 5*7

Instead, it calculated all possible 16 products. What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question here is firstly what enumerate did, and secondly why you're using it. The base function of enumerate is to convert an iterable of the form `(a,b,c)` to an iterable of the form `((start,a), (start+1,b), (start+2,c))`. It adds a new column which is typically used as an index; in your code, this is `i` and `j`. It doesn't change the entries contained in the sequence.

I believe the operation you were intending is a slice, extracting only part of the list:

```
for i, x in enumerate(A):
  for y in A[i+1:]:
    print(x*y)
```

If it is important not to copy the list (it rarely is), you can replace `A[i+1:]` with `itertools.islice(A, i+1, len(A))`.

A side note is that the `start` argument may be useful in the outer loop in this code. We're only using `i+1`, not `i` so we may as well use that value as our index:

```
for nextindex, x in enumerate(A, 1):
  for y in A[nextindex:]:
    print(x*y)
```

Answer (score 7):

The `start` parameter of `enumerate` solely influences the first value of the yielded tuple (i.e. `i` and `j`), it does not influence at which index the enumeration starts. As [the manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) puts it, `enumerate` is equivalent to this:

```
def enumerate(sequence, start=0):
    n = start
    for elem in sequence:
        yield n, elem
        n += 1
```

What you want is this:

```
for i, x in enumerate(A):
    for y in A[i + 1:]:
        print(x * y)
```

Comment: Thanks, I see. No doubt the feature is useful to someone. The choice of name is unfortunate. "The start parameter of enumerate ... does not influence at which index the enumeration starts."